# pythonのpygameでimage.load("")で画像表示ができない

Tags: python, 画像, pygame

現在『ゲームを作りながら楽しく学べるpythonプログラミング』で勉強中の初心者です。本書で、image.load("")ができなくて困っております。

以下のコードを入力して(pythonlogo.jpg)を表示したいのですが、なぜかpygame windowという真っ黒のインターフェース画面が表示されるだけで画像が全く表示がされません。実行ファイルと画像の置き位置がおかしいのかと思い

**draw_image3.py**

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import QUIT

pygame.init()
SURFACE = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

def main():
    """ main routine """

logo = pygame.image.load("pythonlogo.jpg")
theta = 0

while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        theta += 1


        SURFACE.fill((225, 225, 225))

        SURFACE.blit(new_logo, (100, 30))

        # ロゴを回転し左上が(100, 30)の位置にロゴを描画
        new_logo = pygame.transform.rotate(logo, theta)

        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(30)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

検索したら、該当書籍の該当部分が出てきたので見てみたら、まあ入力ミスですね。
質問記事のソースは書籍の記述と違っているので、以下を直してください。

- `logo = pygame.image.load("pythonlogo.jpg")`から`while True:`までのインデントを増やす
- `SURFACE.blit(new_logo, (100, 30))`を`new_logo = pygame.transform.rotate(logo, theta)`の次の行に移動する

内容は書籍の記述そのものなので、全体の修正版記述は止めます。
「入力/転記ミス」に注意してください。

Comment: kunif様　早速のご回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: kunif様　他のプログラムもそうですが、入力ミスが多く、反省しております。しかし、インデントを増やし、「Run Module」を実行しましたところ、「unexpected indent　文字の先頭が赤く表示」され、この表示が出ないようにすると、もとに戻ってしまいました。もちろん、ご指摘の次の行に移動するは、そのように移動しております。画像は同様で、真黒です。ご指示をいただきながら、結果がだせず誠に申し訳ございませんでした。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 書籍に記述してある形と同じになるように入力・整形してください。また、おそらくインデントを形成するのに空白とタブが混在しているのでは？ 見た目は同じでもインデント位置としては違うことになりますので、どちらかに統一してください。